# Inverse of an exponential summatory

Tags: algebra-precalculus

It's the first time for me in this website, and I am never been that good in maths. Anyway, I am trying to figure out if it is possible to find a way to invert an exponential summatory. Saying I have a value $A_{tot}$ which is given by

$$A_{tot} = \sum_{i=1}^N (b_ic)^2$$

where $c$ is a constant, and $b_i$ an $i^{th}$ **random** integer number (unfortunately, I don't know if they are normally distributed or not, does it matter?).

I'd like to derive (even approximated) $A_{tot}$, given I know the value of the sum of the $b$
$$b_{tot} = \sum_{i=1}^N b_i$$
and that each $b_i$ is unknown.

So far I got stuck with resolving something like $\sqrt{b_1c}+ \sqrt{b_2c}+ ...+ \sqrt{b_Nc}$, which (as far as I know), is not possible to simplify by any property.

Is it that all, or is there still something I can do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{i=1}^N (A_i\cos(t))^2$ ? What is $A_i$? What is radq$(A_i)$? What do you mean by '$A_{tot}$ is the result of...' do you mean equal to...? Please edit the question to make these things clear. As it stands it is very hard to understand what you mean.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how to write formulas. Anyway, "cost" is a constant integer (in my specific case 15); Ai is the ith integer number (i=1, 2, ..., N); "radq" is the square root function (just like A^(1/2)); "Atot" is the result of the summation.

Comment: OK. By 'the ith integer number' you mean  $A_i = i$ so that $A_{tot} = \sum_{i=1}^N i^2 c^2 = 1^2c^2 + 2^2 c^2 + 3^2 c^2 \ldots + N^2c^2$ where $c$ is a constant then? Let me know and I can edit the question for you.

Comment: It would be (1c)^2+(2c)^2+(3c)^2+ ... +(Nc)^2. Thanks for the response and help, and sorry for my late answer.

Comment: OK. I have edited the question. If its not what you meant just press 'edit' and make the changes yourself:) I also tried to give you an answer below.

Comment: Thanks. I edited it a bit so that I clarify what I really need. Hope now it's understandable, the original question was not really well written, sorry again.

Comment: You write that you have $A_{tot}$, but then you write that you want to "derive" $A_{tot}$, by which I imagine you mean you want to evaluate $A_{tot}$. But if you have it, you have it. So what do you really mean?

Comment: Anyway, it looks like you know the sum of the $b_i$, and you want to know the sum of the $b_i^2$. But a little experimentation will convince you that this is impossible. E.g., $3+4=7$, and $1+6=7$, but $3^2+4^2\ne1^2+7^2$. So, fuggedaboudid.

Comment: Exactly the point. well I'm a fuggedaboudid I suppose then. Can I accept your comment as answer?

Comment: I encourage you to write it up yourself, and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: The answer below refers to a previous edit of the question.

The sum you are after is $$A_{tot} = \sum_{i=1}^N (ic)^2 = (1c)^2 + (2c)^2+\ldots + (Nc)^2 \\=c^2(1^2+2^2+\ldots + N^2) = c^2\left(\frac{N(N+1)(2N+1)}{6}\right)$$

[since the sum of squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number) is given by $\sum_{i=1}^N i^2 = \frac{N(N+1)(2N+1)}{6}$.

If you are looking for an inverse, i.e. if given $A_{tot}$ what is $N$. Then we can use that for large $N$ then $N+1 \approx N$ and $2N+1\approx 2N$ so $$A_{tot} \approx c^2 \frac{N^3}{3}$$ which gives us the formula

$$N \approx \left\lfloor\left(\frac{3A_{tot}}{c^2}\right)^{1/3}\right\rfloor$$

where $ \lfloor x\rfloor$ is the floor-function (it removes the decimals of $x$ and leaves an integer value, e.g $ \lfloor 3.7\rfloor = 3$ and $ \lfloor 19.2\rfloor = 19$). It turns out that this formula is exact for all $N\geq 1$ (as long as $A_{tot}$ is the result of such a summation).

For example with $c=1$ and $N=3$ we have $A_{tot} = 1 + 2^2 + 3^2 = 14$. Now $\left(\frac{3A_{tot}}{c^2}\right)^{1/3} = 3.48$ and $\lfloor 3.48\rfloor = 3 = N$ showing that it works.

Comment: Winther. I tried your formula in the middle in this form $A_{tot} = c^2 (b_{tot}^3/3)$, according to my wishes (see edited question), but it did not do what I want. Do you perhaps have any suggestion?

Comment: @umbe1987 My answer was to a different interpretation of your question (before the final edit) and does not apply to the final edit. As Gerry says in the comments, what you are after is impossible in general: there is not a formula for $\sum b_i^2$ given only $\sum b_i$.